# iAd covers toolbar

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

From what I have read iAd banners should adjust to the view automatically, but when my banner loads it covers up the toolbar I have at the bottom like so:

[image]

Before the banner loads the toolbar and buttons work fine, but when it loads it 'pushes' the barbuttons up top and you can't click on them. Is there any way to get it to work around my toolbar without just making the toolbar really big in xcode?

Thanks